# How to accept and process external request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, httprequest

Its probably been asked a million times but I can not seem to get the right answer!

How would I make a request to a laravel application externally and process it?

This is what I have so far (built from other stack overflow questions),

**My Website**

```
//Send details to Laravel System
$url = 'http://mylaravelsystem.fake/processExternalData';
$data = array('firstname' => $name_first, 'lastname' => $name_last, 'email_address' => $email, 'method' => 4);
$ch = curl_init($url);
# Form data string
$postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
# Setting our options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
# Get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**My Laravel application**

Routes > api.php

```
Route::post('/processExternalData', 'OptController@insertViaRequest');
```

OptController@insertViaRequest

```
//First create new candidate
$user = new Candidates;
$user->firstname = $request->firstname;
$user->lastname = $request->lastname;
$user->email_address = $request->email_address;
$user->created_by = 1;
if (!$user->save()) {
    Log::info((array) $user->save());
}
```

My task is to be able to send a POST Request to my laravel application and insert it into the database. Am I missing something with the CSRF Token?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I just can not seem to figure it out!

Comment: What part of it isn't working? Is it able to post to the server? Is it hitting the function? Is it logging anything?

Comment: As far as im aware i cant see anything being logged and nothing is processing. I'm wondering if its even being hit, as im not sure how Laravel API/external requests work and how i'm supposed to structure them

Comment: You're creating the context, but not actually doing anything with it, according to your code. I'd suggest using something like curl instead, where you have more control over the process.

Comment: @aynber I have swapped it over to a curl process (edited in question) but it still doesn't do anything

Comment: If you `var_dump($response);` after your curl, what do you get?

Comment: Why don't you return some content from your action and then `echo $response` from CURL to see if it made it in? Also, you can check server logs to see if made it through.

Comment: Try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); to debug curl.. Also I recommend https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle instead of curl.